# Best books for learning about history of airplanes?

Tags: aircraft-design, airplane, books

I've always liked airplanes, but for some reason have never retained much information about specific planes. For instance, if someone casually mentions the X-15 or the X-24, I have to look up what plane they're referring to, and even then I don't know much of their history (with an exception for the Wright Flyer). I'd like to change that and get up to speed with the vernacular and general knowledge of these cool aircraft. Besides the internet, are there any books you would recommend on general aviation history?

Comment: [Wikipedia and the power of the blue link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1ug9-rhSs4&t=67s). I might advise starting with any major manufacture and making use of the "Aircraft Models" section at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

An old, but good, book on aviation tech is The Lore of Flight.  The publication date is circa 1970s, but it’s a decent primer on all aspects of aircraft technology including, history of aircraft, structures, landing gear, powerplant, mission systems, VTOL flight, armament, and general aviation

Comment: That book was on the shelf in the library of my elementary school....